# How to WebView.postUrl() in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, post, webbrowser-control

Having dealt previously with WebView, it distinguishes between [loadUrl()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl%28java.lang.String%29) and [postUrl()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#postUrl%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D%29).

But WebBrowser only has the [Navigate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161356.aspx) method which seems to be taking a different approach by providing (an optional?) postData parameter.

How does that work? Is there a tutorial out there (with sample code) that demonstrates how to use it?

**Update1:** I just found [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3794597/1357272), which doesn't really show any code but cautions in regard to using POST in WebBrowser.

**Update2:** [This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/visualjsharpgeneral/thread/eacb1c98-278b-425b-9d9a-1876603c2dc2) is better than nothing.

Comment: Don't have code sample but maybe [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/975699) can help.

Comment: And code can be found through [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8065856):  [No WebBrowser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/931030) and [Yes WebClient](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPOSTsAndHTTPGETsWithWebClientAndCAndFakingAPostBack.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Forms' WebBrowser you post data by calling the form's [InvokeMember("submit")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299273/how-do-i-submit-a-form-inside-a-webbrowser-control):

If you know the ID of the form you would like to submit:

```
HtmlElement form = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("FormID");
if (form != null)
    form.InvokeMember("submit");
```